# Make a JComboBox editable without affecting its width

Tags: java, swing, width, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` object in my `JFrame` which behaves exactly as expected. However, I'd like to make it editable so that users can input alternative values if necessary. Unfortunately, using `setEditable(true)` to enable editing causes its width to increase significantly. How can I allow editing of the `JComboBox` while keeping its width only as wide as the largest selectable item requires?

The `JComboBox` is in a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout`, however I don't think this is relevant because changing the width of the `JPanel` does not affect the width of the `JComboBox`.

[image: uneditable jComboBox] [image: editable jComboBox]

Comment: So far the only way I found to produce the desired behavior is:  
`comboBox.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 22));`

Comment: What do you mean "the only way". I gave you a solution that allows you to specify the number of characters you want to display, so you don't have to hardcode the actual dimension.

Comment: My apologies. When I initially tried your solution I was running `comboBox.setEditable(true)` before I ran `pack()` which was causing the code not to work. When I moved it after `pack()` your code worked as intended. I'm not sure why it makes a difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JTextField has a default preferred size. It appears that if this size is greater than the preferred rendering size, then the text field size is used. You can change the preferred size by specifying the the number of columns to display in the text field. So you need to manipulate the editor with code something like:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( ... );
comboBox.setEditable( true );
ComboBoxEditor editor = comboBox.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();
textField.setColumns(3);
```

Answer (score 5):

[JComboBox@setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPrototypeDisplayValue%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I tried various values, but none of them had any effect on the width of the `JComboBox`.

Comment: @Altay_H http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194958/fast-replacement-for-jcombobox-basiccomboboxui, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225025/how-to-apply-another-layoutmanager-to-a-jcombobox-multi-column-jcombobox-attemp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242341/jcombobox-change-drop-down-popup,

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... I can't prompt this behavior on my Mac, but you might try creating/adding the combobox, then call

```
Dimension size = box.getSize();
box.setEditable(true);
box.setSize(size); // or box.setMaximumSize(size);
```

Comment: `box.setSize(size)` does not permanently change the width of the jComboBox for me. As soon as `pack()` or `setVisible(true)` occurs the size of box returns to its previous value. Even `setMaximumSize(size)` and `setMinimumSize(size)` are ignored.